# SSH two factor authentication

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, 2-factor-authentication

I have an account on a server that is set up for 2 factor authentication for `ssh`. This is terribly annoying because, even though I have ssh keys set up, I still have to type in a token code every time I ssh to the server. Therefore I was wondering whether there is an `ssh` option which I can use to provide the token code from the command line, something like `ssh --token 1234 user@server.com`. If such an option were available, I could automate the retrieval of the token code and just pass it to ssh so I don't have to type it every time. Alternatively, I would be interested in other options to emulate the typing in bash, such that once the token is prompted, an independent process types it in for me.

Comment: Automating the retrieval of the 2nd factor token would render the concept of 2-factor-authentication useless. But I'm no security expert, so what do I know.

Comment: Not "fixing" two-factor, but avoiding it: ControlMaster/ControlPersist can keep your connection open in the background.

Comment: I'm not sure that 2FA-system is very good in the first place if it is possible to easily fetch the code to the system running SSH. I mean, don't the codes usually come from some standalone keyfob, or to a cellphone. Of course, you could install some software on the phone to transfer the code along... But are you sure whoever it is who's running that server would appreciate it if you tried to circumvent it like that? If this is in a professional context, then trying to work around security policies might be viewed rather dimly. And if it's just a hobby of sorts, then why not disable the 2FA?

Comment: @ilkkachu, you can always get an online phone number to receive text messages. Then all you have to do is to use their API. This doesn't seem to me like a terrible practice since you're still using two separate services for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that `expect` scripts just do that: expect for a string then provide a pre-defined answer to the prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh remote.server.com
expect "password: "
send "P@$$w0rd\r"
interact
```

Requires the `expect` package, `apt install expect`.